# Room on Android Pie

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Room does not work on android api 28.
I get this error: `no such table: user (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):, while compiling: select * from user`

On the other versions, the db works fine. what could be the problem?

```
def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
```

User entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {
@SerializedName("user_id")
@PrimaryKey
private long userId;
@SerializedName("created_at")
private String createdAt;
@Expose
private String lastLogin;
@SerializedName("login_count")
private Integer loginCount;
@Expose
@Embedded
private UserProperties properties;
@IgnoreJson
private long localUpdatedAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
private String updatedAt;
```

Comment: Here you have a table missing, room is working fine. post your code for DAO class and how you are accessing that method from your calling activity.

Comment: Uninstall app from device and then install it again.

Comment: did you changed schema of your user class after installing app ? so, Uninstall app and then install again.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I run the application on a new emulator

Comment: just Uninstall the current app and run again. if same problem coming hen show DAO class